How can I collect VIIRS data automatically for every state?
In my project, I want to collect VIIRS data and get a sum value. After collecting them I downloaded Excel format. In this code, I collected for the USA. I want to collect them automatically for 81 states in Turkey. I have 81 different shape files for them, whose names are 01,02,03...80,81. How can I organize my code to run this code automatically for 81 states ?
// import USA 
var usaBoundary = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-tabakogluayca99/assets/ABD");

// Simplify geomtri
var geometry = usaBoundary.geometry().simplify(10000);  // Toleransı uygun bir şekilde ayarlayın
Map.centerObject(geometry);

var ntlCollection = ee.ImageCollection("NOAA/VIIRS/DNB/ANNUAL_V21");

var startYear = 2014;
var endYear = 2024;

var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(startYear, 1, 1);
var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(endYear + 1, 1, 1);

var band = 'average';

var ntlFiltered = ntlCollection
  .filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate))
  .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(geometry))
  .select(band);
print('Filtered NTL collection', ntlFiltered);
//Map.addLayer(ntlFiltered);

var projection = ntlFiltered.first().projection();
var resolution = projection.nominalScale();
print('NTL Image Resolution', resolution);

// Function to calculate average night light for each image
var calculateAverageLight = function(image) {
  var stats = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), // Use mean reducer for average
    geometry: geometry,
    scale: resolution,
    maxPixels: 1e10
  });
  
  var avgLight = stats.getNumber(band);
  
  var feature = ee.Feature(null, {
    'avg_light': avgLight,
    'system:time_start': image.get('system:time_start')
  });
  
  return feature;
};

// Apply the function to the filtered ImageCollection
var ntlTimeSeriesAvg = ntlFiltered.map(calculateAverageLight);
print('Average Nighttime Lights Time Series', ntlTimeSeriesAvg);

// Create a chart for average nighttime lights
var chartAvg = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature({
  features: ntlTimeSeriesAvg,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start',
  yProperties: ['avg_light']
})
.setChartType('ColumnChart')
.setOptions({
  title: 'Average Nighttime Lights Time Series for ' + 'USA',
  vAxis: {
    title: 'Average Lights',
    viewWindow: {
      min: 0
    },
    gridlines: { color: '#c7beb5' }
  },
  hAxis: {
    title: '',
    format: 'YYYY-MM',
    gridlines: { color: '#c7beb5' }
  },
  legend: { position: 'none' }
});

print(chartAvg);

// Export the first image of the clipped ImageCollection (average lights) to Google Drive

/*
var imageToExportAvg = map_ic.first();

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: imageToExportAvg,
  description: 'VIIRS_Wyoming_Annual_Average_Lights',
  folder: 'GEE_exports',
  region: geometry,
  scale: resolution.toInt(),
  maxPixels: 1e10
});
*/


Are the shape files for the states in 81 different assets?
If so, you can combine them into a single FeatureCollection and then map your current solution over that collection.
If they are already in a single asset and each state is a feature, then you should be able to map over it in the same manner.
